# Does this RewriteRule require the `^` and `$` anchors?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen the following [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) in multiple tutorials.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My question regards the matching pattern:

- `^(.*)$` - Match anything but make sure "anything" is preceded by the start of the line and followed by the end of the line. ‍♂️
- `(.*)` - Match anything

**The `^(.*)$` matching pattern seems to be unnecessarily verbose. Isn't `(.*)` sufficient?**

(I've learned my lesson the hard way that RewriteRules are hard to test so I figured it was worth asking to make sure I'm not missing something obvious)

Comment: Actually, I guess `^` alone for the matching pattern is even more succinct, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just `^` and `$` are not needed even group `(.*)` is not needed here since you're not using `$1` in target.

You can very well write your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

which is equivalent of:

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```